# Use synthetic division to divide $2x^3+6x^2-11x-12$ by $x+4$ I get $2x^2+14x+45+\frac{168}{x+4}$ whereas textbook solution says $2x^2-2x-3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would normally use markup to layout my question but with synthetic division I don't know how to lay it out with markup, so I will post a screen shot.

Question is in the title. I am working on exercise number 23 [here](https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/5-review-exercises). Divide $2x^3+6x^2-11x-12$ by $x+4$ using synthetic division. I got $2x^2+14x+45+\frac{168}{x+4}$ whereas the textbook solution [here](https://openstax.org/books/algebra-and-trigonometry/pages/chapter-5) is  $2x^2-2x-3$.

Here is my working (sorry for giving you a sore neck):
[image]

Where did I go wrong and how can I arrive at $2x^2-2x-3$?

Comment: Watch your signs!  See Ak19's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root is $x = -4$. So you have to take $-4$ instead of $4$

[image]

Hence you have $2x^2-2x-3$

Comment: D'oh! Thank you. Feeling silly now

Comment: You're welcome! I've done the same mistake in the past. It happens :)